# How do I convert zwitterions to neutral form in Avogadro?

Tags: ions, software, molecular-structure

I'd like to be able to convert zwitterions to neutral form in Avogadro if possible. How do I do this?

Comment: What's the purpose?

Comment: To create 3D models of these molecules in neutral form.

Comment: But aminoacids exist exclusively in the zwitterionic form.  The neutral form is never observed.

Comment: True, it's just I've got a Chembox, in which I show the 2D structure of the unionized form and it's nice to have some symmetry even if it isn't realistic. Granted I could display the zwitterionic form in 2D too, but I'm curious as to how I could do it this way if I choose to.

Comment: Let's write down the amino acids in the proper zwitterionic form.  We won't put wrong the wrong ideas into the students' heads if we do that.

Comment: @AbelFriedman Neutral forms are lower in energy over zwitterionic species in the gas phase according to theory.  Besides, it is nice to model both neutral and zwitterionic to compare/contrast the forms in visual form...

Comment: @AbelFriedman The "fact" you stated needs evidence, and I also doubt that very much since absolute statements are almost never true. After all we are dealing with an equilibrium here and in aqueous solution all four forms will be present.

Comment: @Martin is correct.  Theoretical studies have investigated the migration of a proton from the amine to the carboxylic acid (and vice-versa) in small amino acids within a microhydrated environment.  If I recall correctly, the energy required for this process can more than be compensated for under normal conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the neutral protomer of an amino acid can be generated in Avogadro.  What *can* be done is adjusting the protonation state for different values of pH.  That option is in the **Build** menu - **Build**-> **Add Hydrogens for pH**.

Comment: Well, you could do it manually, or protonate the end groups using **Build** -> **Add Hydrogens**